# Can you make a c# application to automatically add post to Yammer?

Tags: c#, windows-services, yammer

I'm trying to write a service application that posts newsfeeds on to yammer when it is triggered.

I found out few examples about web applications or even an application with uses W8. But I want this to be developed inside a service application on W7.

So there can be no interaction to give access to the application or so involving a user who presses a button.

Is anybody who knows this is possible, and if it is possible who can help me creating this.

Thanks in Advance,

Jeroen

Answer (score 3):

The Yammer API is just a REST API (documented here: https://developer.yammer.com/docs/rest-api-rate-limit) and you can use it to post create posts. While the .Net SDK was created for W8, it will work with .Net 4.5 on Windows 7. It may not be perfect of use in a service, but it should be a good starting point you can customize (source code: https://github.com/yammer/dotnet-yammersdk)

Probably the most difficult part in your case will be authentication. In order to access the public API, you'll first need to create you own 3rd party application (see API docs) and go through the OAuth flow. Assuming your service is not going to allow users to log in with their own individual credentials, you'll probably need to create some sort of non-user bot account within your Yammer network and have the your service use those credentials to authenticate to the API. Once you have authenticated, you can

Answer (score 0):

There is a .Net SDK, which might be useful, it also has some examples:

https://developer.yammer.com/docs/net-sdk

Comment: That SDK I have, but you can only use the examples from Windows 8 or higher, so looking for someone who has done this from Windows 7 machine.